# Why when i click on the "Sync" button inside my document library, the SharePoint workspace's account configuration wizard will be opened

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, administration, sync

I have an enterprise on-premises sharepoint server 2013. now i have a site collection of type team site. and i have enabled the publishing features inside it.

now inside the document library ,i click on the Sync button, as follow:-

[image]

as i want to have a folder inside my PC which represents the document library, so i can work on the documents even if i do not have network connection.
but when i click on the above Sync button, i got this sharepoint workspace's account setting wizard as follow:-
[image]

so i am not sure why i got this wizard, instead of the sync app wizard?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have one drive for business installed?

Comment: @AmalHashim you mean the one drive installed on my windows 7 PC? or installed inside sharepoint server ?

Comment: In your machine

Comment: @AmalHashim no i only have Groove installed

Comment: Install One Drive and then you can sync easily

Comment: @AmalHashim ok but does Groove provides an alternative for one drive? i mean they can be used to sync sharepoint documents inside my PC to work on the docs offline ?

Comment: One Drive is the way to go - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Which-version-of-OneDrive-am-I-using-19246eae-8a51-490a-8d97-a645c151f2ba

Comment: @AmalHashim now why i am a bot confused, because when i worked on some sharepoint online projects, the sharepoint online have an integration with OneDrive, so i thought that one drive is a cloud based application. but seem there is a desktop based version of the OneDrive which works similar to the Groove which i have.. are my points valid ?

Comment: Groove is the older version of One Drive.. Going forward you should use One Drive.. please read the link I shared in my previous comment

Comment: @AmalHashim now i download OneDrive inside my windows 7 PC, so now i have Groove & OneDrive installed.. but now when i open the OneDrive it ask me to sign-in so not sure what does this mean? now in our case we have sharepoint 2013 on-premises (not office 365) .. so does OneDrvie allow me to download and sync document inside my PC, so i can read these documents offline ??? i am a bit confused on the use for OneDrive ?? is it an application to download and sync sharepoint documents inside my PC??